# Can we set the multiple generic arguments with -D option in GenericOptionsParser?

Tags: hadoop, command-line-arguments, jvm-arguments

I want to pass multiple configuration parameters to my Hadoop job through GenericOptionsParser.

With "-D abc=xyz" I can pass one argument and able to retrieve the same from the configuration object but I am not able to pass the multiple argument.

Is it possible to pass multiple argument?If yes how?

Answer (score 4):

Passed the parameters as `-D color=yellow -D number=10`

Had the following code in the run() method

```
String color = getConf().get("color");
System.out.println("color = " + color);

String number = getConf().get("number");
System.out.println("number = " + number);
```

The following was the o/p in the console

```
color = yellow
number = 10
```

Comment: in this case I am getting 
color = yellow
number = null

Comment: You might have missed something - Nija is also able to do it as mentioned in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran in to this issue after upgrading from Hadoop 1.2.1 to Hadoop 2.4.1. The problem is that Hadoop's dependency on commons-cli 1.2 was being omitted due to a conflict with commons-cli 1.1 that was pulled in from Cassandra 2.0.5.

After a quick look through the source it looks like commons-cli options that have an uninitialized number of values (what Hadoop's GenericOptionsParser does) default to a limit of 1 in version 1.1 and no limit in 1.2.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I tested passing multiple parameters and I used the `-D` flag multiple times.

$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar /path/to/my.jar **-D mapred.heartbeats.in.second=80 -D mapred.map.max.attempts=2** ...`

Doing this changed the values to what I specified in the Job's configuration.

Comment: Actually it's the other way. According to the [Hadoop - The Definitive Guide](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920010388.do) - `Do not confuse setting Hadoop properties using the -D property=value option to GenericOptionsParser (and ToolRunner) with setting JVM system properties using the -Dproperty=value option to the java command. The syntax for JVM system properties does not allow any whitespace between the D and the property name, whereas GenericOptionsParser requires them to be separated by whitespace.`